# Helm template default value unexpected \\ in operand

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I try to use a default string value but doesnt work out

I just used the official helm example:
https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-default-function.

For both of:

```
drink: {{ .Values.favorite.drink | default "tea" | quote }}
drink: {{ .Values.favorite.drink | default "tea" }}
```

I get a

> unexpected "\\" in operand

error

without quoting(which is non-string) it works:

```
drink: {{ .Values.favorite.drink | default 34 }}
drink: {{ .Values.favorite.drink | default false }}
```

Comment: `drink: {{ .Values.favorite.drink | default "tea" | quote }}` worked for me